# Smart Contract Write Gas Fee

Tags: gas, etherscan

What is the price of interacting with your own smart contract(Write)? I am planning to deploy my own smart contract and I am planning ahead. I was interacting with a random smart contract on the "write" side. The gas fee would cost about $10,000. Now is that because it's someone else's smart contract and not mine. Would the gas fee be the same for me to interact with my own smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how complex the computation is from the function you are calling in the smart contract.

*"Gas refers to the unit that measures the amount of computational effort required to execute specific operations."*

I recommend reading about the Ethereum basics here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#what-is-gas

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @jcalb, the fee depends on the computation, as well as the price you pay per computation "step".

A fee of $10,000 could be for a computation that uses 1,000,000 `gas`, and you paying a `gas price` of 1 cent per gas (which is extremely high).

`Gas price` is typically denominated in gigawei (gwei), which is 1 billionth of an ether.

Unless you're paying a very high `gas price`, your fees should be much lower.